# Where should python wrapper/package be installed

Tags: python, debian

I am distributing a reasonably large C library; as part of the distribution is a Python wrapper package. The build system is `cmake`, and `make install` should copy the Python code to a location in the Python path. Based on reading the Python documentation the default location for the installed Python modules is:

```
${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
```

But on Debian based system this path is not on the default Python search path, instead the search path contains `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`. I would like a default installation to "just work" and wonder what is the best approach with respect to `dist-packages` versus `site-packages`? My current plan is:

1. If on Debian based based system - install to `dist-packages`.
2. Else install to `site-packages`

But maybe `dist-packages` is *only* for packages which come with a package manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dist-packages** are only for packages which come with a package manager.

From debian wiki :

> dist-packages instead of site-packages. Third party Python software installed from Debian packages goes into dist-packages, not site-packages. This is to reduce conflict between the system Python, and any from-source Python build you might install manually.

For packaging python modules, refer [Section 2.5](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-paths)

> Public Python modules not handled by python-central or python-support must be installed in the system Python modules directory, /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages for python2.6 and later, and /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages for python2.5 and earlier. Public Python 3 modules must be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

Comment: OK - the problem with that is that without manipulations of $PYTHONPATH or alternatively the site initialization, the Python interpreter will not find my package.

Comment: I am uncertain: But the way I read the debian wiki it could be interpreted that site-packages is for a from-source Python distribution - I just have a from-source Python module - using the standard distribution of Python?

Comment: Yes, site-packages are for from source python distribution. Reworded the answer.

Comment: Thank you; this is not crystal clear to me, but to me to the final conclusion seems to me that I will use dist-packages, although typically with prefix /usr/local. For what it is worth I have a Python package, not just a module.